# Best practices for using SQS with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, amazon-sqs, consumer

I need to consume SQS events with my rails application. I've written a Sidekiq job which does a long polling like this:

```
class SqsConsumerWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  
  def perform
    ...
    poller = Aws::SQS::QueuePoller.new(<queue_url>, client: <sqs_instance>)
    poller.poll(wait_time_seconds: 20, max_number_of_messages: 10, visibility_timeout: 180) do |messages|
      messages.each do |message|
        puts message.inspect
      end
    end  
  end
end
```

First problem was when to initiate this job. Currently I've moved the invocation to rails initializer where I've overriden the Sidekiq `config.on(:startup)` block to call this job. This will help me to start the job on every deployment. (I have also written some logic in this initializer to check the number of workers are not above some limit etc.)

I wanted to understand is there a better way to solve this problem? I've seen the gem [shoryuken](https://github.com/ruby-shoryuken/shoryuken) which abstracts out these things. But I need more control over the consumer and thought of having my own implementation. I also need to understand how to scale up and scale down the number of consumers with this approach.

Comment: Hi @vijith-mv, just wondering, in which way you went through finally?

Comment: Hey @JunanChakma I ended up using the shoryuken library